# [Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside se.... I read post related to this error and understood the cause of error, but I'm not sure what to do

Tags: vue.js

I have encounted the below error.
[Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.

This error occurs when await keyword is behind inject().
useRoute() and useRouter() use inject() internally.

I knew the meaning of error and I assume that the await keyword is the cause of the error.

But I'm not sure what to do.

Could you tell me what code I should modify?

Here is my code.

```
// router.js

import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import CategoryHome from './components/CategoryHome.vue'
import CategoryShow from './components/CategoryShow.vue'

const routes = [
    (abbreviation)
]

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
    (abbreviation)
})

export default router
```

```
// function.js


import { ref } from "vue"


import router from './router.js'

let categoryId = ''

export async function initial() {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get('/api/max')
        categoryId = res.data.id
        router.push({name: 'category.show', params: { categoryId: categoryId }})
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('error handling')
    }

}
```

```
// CategoryHome.vue

<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue"

import * as func from '../functions.js'
import router from '../router.js'

const newCategory = ref('')

onMounted(() => {
    func.initial()
})
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. The question doesn't contain the code that causes this error

Comment: OK! I rewirte my question again.